# Publish articles automatically

Tags: c#, xml

I will be given url having XML that has information about some topic. I can extract that information easily but is it possible to post that article on a website if i am user of that website and fill the information got in the website using c#??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends very much on the web site. What protocol does it uses, does it require users to be authenticated in order to post articles, does the site provides a functionality to post articles at all?

With C# you can easily use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to post whatever you information want to any web site.

Comment: Yes it requires user to Log In and yes it supports article auto Publish and it has some modules for joomla wordpress for auto publish

Comment: how can i find feild name where to add value